# Combine Multiple child rows

Tags: mysql

Thanks in advance, I just can't seem to get it!

I have two tables

**Category**

```
Id  Name
1   Aptitude
2   English
```

**Mark**

```
UserId  CategoryId   Mark
  1        1          25
  1        2          45
  2        1          34
  3        2          45
  4        1          56
  4        2          66
```

What I am looking to output is a mysql query is something to this effect

**Output**

```
UserId  AptitudeMark   EnglishMark
  1        25            45
  4        56            66
```

As I am new to mysql I could only get either one category or the other category and I can't get them in the same row as well. Also when the user is having both the category mark, we should consider.

Comment: Do you have only two categories?

Comment: @ArunKrish No it has many

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can achieve this with the following query with `CASE` expression and `GROUP BY` clause, if the number of  `category`(s) is fixed.

**Query**

```
select * from
(
    select UserId,
    max(case when CategoryId = 1 then Mark else null end) as AptitudeMark,
    max(case when CategoryId = 2 then Mark else null end) as EnglishMark
    from Mark
    group by UserId
)t
where t.AptitudeMark is not null
and t.EnglishMark is not null;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT main.`id`,A.mark as AptitudeMark,E.mark as EnglishMark FROM `Mark` as main
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id,mark FROM `Mark` WHERE `CategoryId` = 1) as  A ON main.id = A.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id,mark FROM `Mark` WHERE `CategoryId` = 2) as  E ON main.id = E.id
GROUP BY main.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `GROUP_CONCAT`, but the results will be somewhat different. Have a look at this:

```
SELECT `UserId`, GROUP_CONCAT(`CategoryId`), GROUP_CONCAT(`Mark`) FROM `marks`
GROUP BY `UserID`
```

Comment: This query is giving me all the users praveen. Can you please tell me how to add a condition in which only user who has entry for all the category should be in output.

Comment: @SubashL How do you know if the user has entry in all the category?

Comment: If you look at the Mark table, you will not find all the category for userid 2 and 3.

Comment: @SubashL Your Database Structure seems to be right, but bringing it in this way is not possible just with SQL I guess, I can do it using PHP.

Answer (score 1):

If the categories are unknown then you will need to use dynamic sql for this and the query would look like

```
set @sql = null;
select
  group_concat(distinct
    concat(
      'max(case when m.CategoryId = ''',
     m.CategoryId,
      ''' then m.Mark end) AS ',
      concat(c.Name,'Mark')
    )
  ) into @sql
from Mark m join Category c on c.Id = m.CategoryId ;

set @sql = concat('select m.UserId, ', @sql, ' from Mark m
                  join Category c on c.Id = m.CategoryId
                  group by m.UserId
');

prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

Here is a test case

```
mysql> select * from Category ;
+------+----------+
| Id   | Name     |
+------+----------+
|    1 | Aptitude |
|    2 | English  |
+------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from Mark ;
+--------+------------+------+
| UserId | CategoryId | Mark |
+--------+------------+------+
|      1 |          1 |   25 |
|      1 |          2 |   45 |
|      2 |          1 |   34 |
|      3 |          2 |   45 |
|      4 |          1 |   56 |
|      4 |          2 |   66 |
+--------+------------+------+

6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Running above query will give

```
+--------+--------------+-------------+
| UserId | AptitudeMark | EnglishMark |
+--------+--------------+-------------+
|      1 |           25 |          45 |
|      2 |           34 |        NULL |
|      3 |         NULL |          45 |
|      4 |           56 |          66 |
+--------+--------------+-------------+
```

Comment: This query is giving me all the users abhik. Can you please tell me how to add a condition in which only user who has entry for all the category should be in output. In this case only the userid 1 and 4

Comment: @SubashL : just give the condition to get `AptitudeMark` and  `EnglishMark` is not null

Comment: well @Ullas its more than that when you do not know how many categories will be there. if there are just 2 category adding a not null will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT UserId, GROUP_CONCAT(CategoryId,'-',Mark) AS Category_mark
FROM marks
GROUP BY UserId
```

Which will give you the result like

```
UserId  Category_mark
  1      1-25,2-45,
```

Comment: Please tell me how to separate the category_mark column into separate column like my output.